# How to get the average CPU usage over the past 10 seconds in bash?

Tags: linux, command-line, scripting, sudo, cpu

I need a command that would `echo` the average CPU usage over the past 10 seconds in Ubuntu 18.

Each of the following conditions must be met:

1. It must be lightweight with a very small footprint, running a
   background script constantly writing to the filesystem is a no no.
2. The value must account for number of cores automatically (I don't
   know the number of cores prior).
3. The value must be a number between
   0 and 1. There shouldn't be any other output as it will be read by a
   script, not a human. Alternatively suggest a robust algorithm of parsing the output of the suggested command, whatever it is.
4. `sudo` requirement is fine, but the script *must* be able to be run as a command over SSH and it must have a proper process return behavior (`0` exit code for success).

Built-in commands and untilities are preferred, but additional software is OK too as long as it's available in the official repos.

Comment: When you say average, how many samples are you willing to take in ten seconds?

Comment: The more the better, but I think one each 1-3 seconds is fine.

Comment: Just to be clear: you want to have just one command line or a script ?

Comment: You could [start with this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229580/5395338), then create a simple shell script to execute it periodically with `sleep` periods in between.

Comment: @Seamus I wanted to avoid that approach..

Comment: @TonyBogdanov What approach? With `sleep`, a script?

Comment: @Paradox Writing to the filesystem thousands of times a day.

Comment: @TonyBogdanov Reading or writing? If that's reading, do not forget that `/proc` is a **virtual** filesystem, which is updated **only** when accessed. If that's writing, you can write a chunk of data in one time not just one value. But at some, you will need some persistent data. Either way, please elaborate because I do not see the issue seeing what you use case is.

Comment: @TonyBogdanov If you have any idea on how you plan to write on disk, that would be helpful to help you out.

Comment: @Paradox Actually I don't need to write to disk at all. If `/proc` is kept in the RAM then there's absolutely no problem at all. The script will be running *always* at *all* times. I don't really need the info if the script stops for some reason (no need for "historical" data). As long as it is guaranteed that there will be no writing to the disk, ever, I'm fine with the approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sysstat` package provides `sar`, a system activity data collector.

```
sar -u ALL 10 1
```

posts **average** cpu stats of the **next** 10 seconds since starting the command. The output is like

```
Linux 5(...)    11/05/21        _x86_64_        (1 CPU)

17:22:35        CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
17:22:36        all      8.85     20.75      2.46      0.00      0.00     67.94
Average:        all      8.85     20.75      2.46      0.00      0.00     67.94
```

Comment: It's a very old question and I no longer need a solution, but yours is a nice one nonetheless!